# What are the benefits/disadvantages of splitting up checkout process

Tags: forms, interaction-design, checkout

The purchase page (https://staging.volcanicpixels.com/ssl/buy) has quite a few fields on it and I'm considering splitting it up however I'm not sure whether that would actually improve the process at all - personally I like being able to see the whole process on one page (so I have a clear idea of how long it will take and what payment methods are available to me).

Feel free to give the checkout process a go, it's the sandbox site so you can use the following credit card:

4242 4242 4242 4242 with any valid expiry date and CVC.

Answer (score 1):

Luke W has repeatedly mentioned that it makes little difference http://alistapart.com/article/testing-accordion-forms

See also this article of his on ecommerce checkouts http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1579#webform